# SoftArtisans library and Excel 97 compatibility vs 1048576 limit rows bug report

Tags: excel, officewriter

SoftArtisans trigger run-time exception in regards of 65536 max rows. The most strange is I use Office 2016 which have 1 048 576 max rows.

I am now using Office 2016 which have max cell rows count equal to 1 048 576. When I use your library it seems max rows are 65536 (Office 97 compatibility). Should I need to buy a new version to use 1048576 limit rows?

Excel limits:
Excel 97/200/2003 has a 65536 row limit by 256 columns
Excel 2007/2010/2016, the maximum worksheet size is 1048576 rows by 16384 columns

Answer (score 1):

You need a newer version of office writer that supports XLSX file formats which have the new row limit.

Comment: I am afraid of that ;( Still thank you. If you find a workaround for the old version please let as now and I will speak with my manager to send you our license. We do not have a new license for the new version. The main problem is  SoftArtisans do not send any offer or promotion price for upgrade to the old type of clients which is very bad.

Comment: I would email contact@Softartisans.com they have always been helpful to me.